# i send a post request in symfony and this is what i get

Tags: php, symfony, postman

I made this function and tried to use `POST` method in postman but I have no idea why I get that response, also the entity has a relation to it which is project and organization:

```
/**
 * @Route("/workspaces/addTask", name="app_api" , methods={"POST"})
 */
public function addTask(Request $request): Response
{
    $workspace =new Workspaces();
    $parameter = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
    dd($parameter);

    $workspace->setName($parameter['name']);
    $workspace->setOrganisation($parameter['Organisation']);
    $workspace->setProject($parameter['Project']);

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($workspace);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->json('insert done');
}
```

And this is the response I get in Postman and it does make no sense to me:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
"title": "An error occurred",
"status": 500,
"detail": "Too few arguments to function App\\Controller\\api\\projects\\WorkspacesController::addTask(), 0 passed in C:\\Users\\benbi\\Desktop\\EMb\\1\\WorCal_API\\src\\Controller\\api\\projects\\WorkspacesController.php on line 75 and exactly 1 expected",
"class": "ArgumentCountError",
"trace": [
    {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "C:\\Users\\benbi\\Desktop\\EMb\\1\\WorCal_API\\src\\Controller\\api\\projects\\WorkspacesController.php",
        "line": 117,
        "args": []
    }
```

Comment: Is service injection properly set up ? In your `services.yml`. Also, do your WorkspacesController extend any class ?

Comment: WorkspacesController extend to a rest class but the problem is within that function cause other test functions works fine